# Move large amount of files between libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, move

We have a library with nearly 1TB of data stored in around 5M files. These need to be moved to another library on the same SPO site because at the moment the files files are stored in the default library which causes problems for the users who sync it with Windows Explorer.

The "Move" option in SPO is limited to 30k files and 100GB data per operation.

Is there a way with "Power Automate" or PowerShell to move the data across the libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Try out [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/), it is the best tool for migration SharePoint.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use 3rd party tools and must rely on MS products only.

Comment: Then use PowerShell,
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-file-between-document-libraries-using-powershell.html